# Single-word alternative to "countable on fingers"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that describes the idiom "countable on fingers" to be preferably used as an adjective.

Comment: By "countable on fingers", you mean between 0 and 10?

Comment: If you don't mind hyphens and are flexible about 10, "single-digit" is almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

'Countable on Fingers' is not idiomatic.

But assuming you mean something one ['Can count on the fingers of one hand'](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can+count+on+the+fingers+of+one+hand#:%7E:text=A%20phrase%20used%20to%20emphasize%20that%20something%20happens%20rarely.&text=getting%20it%20back.-,I%20can%20count%20on%20the%20fingers%20of%20one%20hand,of%20times%20he%27s%20repaid%20me.) It just means "A small number" so, **few**, **low**, or **small** would be appropriate alternatives, depending on the exact context.